# how to secure a MyCloud? Is it already too late?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, stack-smash

My laptop is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have a WMD MyCloud that I am doing backups to with an rsync. The rsync calls usually end with an error.

Some things I have observed. The MyCloud machine has a REST API and I see that someone has tried to hack that. As far as I can tell, the attempt did not succeed.

My backup does this from my laptop, to the MyCloud:

```
 /usr/bin/rsync -a -z -v /home/me/ root@192.168.1.82:/shares/me
```

Usually I get:

```
 rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (93239 bytes received so far) [sender]
 rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
```

and the rsync process is returning 12.

Oddly, if I use a second -v, the process usually succeeds. Why would that be? It is too fast without the second -v?

Something I saw worries me. Again, this is the output on my laptop, running rsync to copy to the MyCloud:

```
 *** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
 rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (11387 bytes received so far) [sender]
 rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
```

and it returns 12. Ouch!

So, does this mean my laptop is infected with something, presumably Heartbleed or something like it?

On my laptop:

```
 $ rsync -h
 rsync  version 3.1.0  protocol version 31
 ...
```

On the MyCloud:

```
 # rsync -h
 rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30
 ...
```

Am I just screwed? Do I just need to update the stuff on the MyCloud? I have updated by Ubuntu laptop several times. Did that not prevent an infection on this machine?

Open to any suggestions.